# How to add a link to a Visio document via Python

Tags: python, visio, win32com

I googled for some code to create Visio documents via Python. I want to add shapes, and have hyperlinks. So that you can click on the shape, or preferably on the text inside the shape, and get to a URL.

```
import os
import win32com.client

from win32com.client import constants

appVisio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
appVisio.Visible =1

doc = appVisio.Documents.Add("Basic Diagram.vst")
pagObj = doc.Pages.Item(1)
stnObj = appVisio.Documents("Basic Shapes.vss")
mastObj = stnObj.Masters("Rectangle")

shpObj1 = pagObj.Drop(mastObj, 4.25, 5.5)
shpObj1.Text = "This is some text."

shpObj2 = pagObj.Drop(mastObj, 2, 2)
shpObj2.Text = """This is some more text. {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com/"}{\fldrslt http://www.google.com}}"""


connectorMaster = appVisio.Application.ConnectorToolDataObject

connector = pagObj.Drop(connectorMaster, 0, 0)
connector.Cells("BeginX").GlueTo(shpObj1.Cells("PinX"))
connector.Cells("EndX").GlueTo(shpObj2.Cells("PinX"))

doc.SaveAs(r'C:\utils\MyDrawing.vsd')
doc.Close()

appVisio.Visible =0
appVisio.Quit()
```

The RTF link is ignored - I tried that. Visio can add hyperlinks in the UI. So... does anyone know how I can add a link via Python here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio only supports links on a shape (rather than within the text itself).  A shape has [Hyperlinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff766930.aspx) collection of [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767835.aspx) objects and so you can add as follows:

```
# shpObj2.Text = """This is some more text. {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com/"}{\fldrslt http://www.google.com}}"""
shpObj2.Text = "This is a shape with multiple links."

shp2Hyperlink1 = shpObj2.Hyperlinks.Add()
shp2Hyperlink1.Name = "Google"
shp2Hyperlink1.Address = "http://www.google.com"

shp2Hyperlink2 = shpObj2.Hyperlinks.Add()
shp2Hyperlink2.Name = "BBC"
shp2Hyperlink2.Address = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
```

Under the covers this is just writing cells into the ShapeSheet:
[image: Visio Hyperlinks ShapeSheet section]